# Getting "Editor" field value throws the value range exception under a non-System account

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Below's the piece of legacy code of migration from 2007 to 2010. It gets the values of the author and the editor fields. The values are the same user, actually. When I login under the SPAdmin rights, both fields work okay. However, under a test account, the attempt to get the value of the Editor field fails with the following exception: "Value does not fall within the expected range", while the Author field still works fine. Let's see the code:

```
SPQuery sPQuery = new SPQuery();
sPQuery.Query = queryString;
sPQuery.ExpandRecurrence = true;
sPQuery.CalendarDate = startDateTime;
sPQuery.DatesInUtc = false;



SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(sPQuery);
SPListItem item = items[0];

object author = item["Author"]; //works always, under any account
object editor = item["Editor"]; // **doesn't work under non-system account**
```

Well, here is the line of code that always works for the Editor too:

```
object editor = item.ParentList.GetItemById(item.ID)["Editor"];
```

So I wonder what wrong with that and what should I check.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem was in the the lookup threshold limitation.

Comment: Hello mishau, im facing same issue. im using SPGridView and if i want to show Editor field from SPDataSource and i use some other then system account i get same error as you. Ho you solve this problem? whats mean lookup trashold limitation?

Comment: Actually, I havent worked with SP for a year, but if I remember corerectly, you can have visible only 8 lookup fields in one list . So if your list contains more than 8 lookups you may come across some issues with visibility and displaying those fields or even with getting values form those fields like in my case. User fields are also lookup fields.